# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple slf4j bindings with only one jar file

Tags: java, spring, junit, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to build a test framework using ant and initiating spring context from the main unit test suite class file. I am getting a multiple slf4j bindings error but they refer to the same jar file.

```
[junit] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/demo/server/lib/apache-activemq-5.5.0/optional/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[junit] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/demo/server/lib/apache-activemq-5.5.0/optional/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Possibly you have the same JAR file on the classpath twice.  Possibly the bindings are being resolved twice?  Maybe on two different classloaders?  This could just be an informational message that you could ignore.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding your environment?